# Get Thread By Name

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I have a multithreaded application and I assign a unique name to each thread through `setName()` property. Now, I want functionality to get access to the threads directly with their corresponding name.

Somethings like the following function:

```
public Thread getThreadByName(String threadName) {
    Thread __tmp = null;

    Set<Thread> threadSet = Thread.getAllStackTraces().keySet();
    Thread[] threadArray = threadSet.toArray(new Thread[threadSet.size()]);

    for (int i = 0; i < threadArray.length; i++) {
        if (threadArray[i].getName().equals(threadName))
            __tmp =  threadArray[i];
    }

    return __tmp;
}
```

The above function checks all running threads and then returns the desired thread from the set of running threads. Maybe my desired thread is interrupted, then the above function won't work. Any ideas on how to incorporate that functionality?

Comment: How are the threads being created?

Comment: Just store the threads you need in a `HashMap<String, Thread>` by their names.

Comment: @JohnVint Threads being created in another class, so that's why I can't access them directly.

Comment: @DKN Sounds like you need a Singleton.

Comment: @DKN There really isn't a generic example to be made. Surely you know how to use `HashMap`s, so have one serving as a thread registry that's accessible at 1. where the threads are being created, and 2. where you need to retrieve them. These two depend heavily on how your application is structured internally.

Comment: @DKN If you cannot get a hold of the thread after it's created and before it is interrupted you are out of luck.  If the thread is interrupted and the exception propagates outside of the `run` method the thread will probably become unreachable and GC'd.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can find all *active* threads using [ThreadGroup](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ThreadGroup.html):

- Get your current thread's group
- Work your way up the threadgroup hierarchy by calling `ThreadGroup.getParent()` until you find a group with a null parent.
- Call `ThreadGroup.enumerate()` to find all threads on the system.

The value of doing this completely escapes me ... what will you possibly do with a named thread? Unless you're subclassing `Thread` when you should be implementing `Runnable` (which is sloppy programming to start with).

Comment: One use case for this is to find an local variable thread (meaning reflection cannot get to it) defined in a third-party library (meaning source code cannot be modified easily) which has a name specified to set an uncaught exception handler (because they failed to allow for logging when an exception is thrown here). This is a very special case, but there are edge cases for this situation.

Comment: In my case, I'm using it to write a unit test to debug a thread with suspected thread-safety issue.  The thread in question implements Runnable, but the question is: what is the alternative answer?  How do you get a particular Runnable by name?

Comment: Another use case could be a library that provides (inside something more complex) a way to create a named thread, but wants to check that this thread is created only once (with not many thread-safety guarantees, but still...)

Answer (score 26):

An iteration of Pete's answer..

```
public Thread getThreadByName(String threadName) {
    for (Thread t : Thread.getAllStackTraces().keySet()) {
        if (t.getName().equals(threadName)) return t;
    }
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

I like the HashMap idea best, but if you want to keep the Set, you can iterate over the Set, rather than going through the setup of converting to an array:

```
Iterator<Thread> i = threadSet.iterator();
while(i.hasNext()) {
  Thread t = i.next();
  if(t.getName().equals(threadName)) return t;
}
return null;
```

Comment: This like the above example, won't work if thread is interrupted!

Answer (score 0):

That's how I did it on the basis of [this](http://nadeausoftware.com/articles/2008/04/java_tip_how_list_and_find_threads_and_thread_groups):

```
/*
    MIGHT THROW NULL POINTER
 */
Thread getThreadByName(String name) {
    // Get current Thread Group
    ThreadGroup threadGroup = Thread.currentThread().getThreadGroup();
    ThreadGroup parentThreadGroup;
    while ((parentThreadGroup = threadGroup.getParent()) != null) {
        threadGroup = parentThreadGroup;
    }
    // List all active Threads
    final ThreadMXBean threadMXBean = ManagementFactory.getThreadMXBean();
    int nAllocated = threadMXBean.getThreadCount();
    int n = 0;
    Thread[] threads;
    do {
        nAllocated *= 2;
        threads = new Thread[nAllocated];
        n = threadGroup.enumerate(threads, true);
    } while (n == nAllocated);
    threads = Arrays.copyOf(threads, n);
    // Get Thread by name
    for (Thread thread : threads) {
        System.out.println(thread.getName());
        if (thread.getName().equals(name)) {
            return thread;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: No reason to do it through JMX interfaces when you have direct APIs.