# How can I be notified when a thread (that I didn't start) ends?

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a library in a Jar file that needs to keep track of how many threads that use my library. When a new thread comes in is no problem: I add it to a list. But I need to remove the thread from the list when it dies.

This is in a Jar file so I have no control over when or how many threads come through. Since I didn't start the thread, I cannot force the app (that uses my Jar) to call a method in my Jar that says, "this thread is ending, remove it from your list". I'd **REALLY** rather not have to constantly run through all the threads in the list with Thread.isAlive().

By the way: this is a port of some C++ code which resides in a DLL and easily handles the DLL_THREAD_DETACH message. I'd like something similar in Java.

Edit:

The reason for keeping a list of threads is: we need to limit the number of threads that use our library - for business reasons. When a thread enters our library we check to see if it's in the list. If not, it's added. If it is in the list, we retrieve some thread-specific data. When the thread dies, we need to remove it from the list. Ideally, I'd like to be notified when it dies so I can remove it from the list. I can store the data in ThreadLocal, but that still doesn't help me get notification of when the thread dies.

Edit2:
Original first sentence was: "I have a library in a Jar file that needs to keep track of threads that use objects in the library."

Comment: Possible related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15370120/get-thread-by-name

Comment: is a thread holding a resource which needs to be cleaned up after the fact?

Comment: jtahlborn: no, it's not holding a resource. A thread comes in, does some work for a bit, then goes away.

Comment: Does your library create the threads?

Comment: @NESPowerGlove: No.  Someone changed the title of this question. It was: "How can I be notified when a thread, *that I didn't start*, ends?"

Comment: @printffan So you don't start the threads, and you also don't hand off the Thread objects then right? Because if you did you could hand off custom Thread objects that can callback when they are done.

Comment: @NESPowerGlove: correct: I don't hand out the Thread objects.

Comment: will a thread be in a single method the whole time, or calling in and out of multiple methods (you could use a finally block).  why do you need to know when a thread is done?  maybe if you explained your use case better, we could give better suggestions.

Comment: Why do you need the list of threads? Do you store thread-related information? (You could use a ThreadLocal for that).

Comment: I question the “need to keep track of threads that use objects”. But anyway, the assumption that a thread that has used an object in the past is using it until it dies is completely wrong. It might use your object for a second and then never again during the remaining weeks of its lifetime. So it doesn’t matter if you detect the thread’s death immediately or after the next gc-cycle as in the proposed answer. Your code is broken anyway.

Comment: @jtahlborn: the thread will span multiple methods. See my edit for a description of what we're trying to do...

Comment: @Holger: Thanks, yeah I misspoke. I don't really need to keep track of the objects any threads use. I just need to keep track of the threads themselves. I'll clean that up...

Comment: so, unless you are expecting a high turnover on threads, i would expect my answer would probably be sufficient.  the gc is pretty aggressive at reclaiming WeakReferences.

Comment: Your edit #1 is a critical piece of information. And it leads to the question: why do you need to be notified *as soon as* a thread finishes? It would be far simpler, imo, to perform all checks passively, especially since you're already maintaining a table of threads.

Comment: @jtahlborn: I don't want to assume a low turnover. High thread turnover is quite possible.  But I will look at WeakReferences.  Thanks

Comment: @kdgregory: The customer is paying us for how many threads that they want to run through our library. Therefore, we want to have an accurate count. As I said, the DLL_THREAD_DETACH works great for us in C++ and I was hoping for something similar in Java.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your edits, your real problem is *not* tracking when a thread dies, but instead limiting access to your library. Which is good, because there's no portable way to track when a thread dies (and certainly no way within the Java API).

I would approach this using a passive technique, rather than an active technique of trying to generate and respond to an event. You say that you're already creating thread-local data on entry to your library, which means that you already have the cutpoint to perform a passive check. I would implement a `ThreadManager` class that looks like the following (you could as easily make the methods/variables static):

```
public class MyThreadLocalData {
    // ...
}

public class TooManyThreadsException
extends RuntimeException {
    // ...
}

public class ThreadManager
{
    private final static int MAX_SIZE = 10;

    private ConcurrentHashMap<Thread,MyThreadLocalData> threadTable = new ConcurrentHashMap<Thread,ThreadManager.MyThreadLocalData>();
    private Object tableLock = new Object();

    public MyThreadLocalData getThreadLocalData() {
        MyThreadLocalData data = threadTable.get(Thread.currentThread());
        if (data != null) return data;

        synchronized (tableLock) {
            if (threadTable.size() >= MAX_SIZE) {
                doCleanup();
            }            

            if (threadTable.size() >= MAX_SIZE) {
                throw new TooManyThreadsException();
            }

            data = createThreadLocalData();
            threadTable.put(Thread.currentThread(), data);
            return data;
        }
    }
```

The thread-local data is maintained in `threadTable`. This is a `ConcurrentHashMap`, which means that it provides fast concurrent reads, as well as concurrent iteration (that will be important below). In the happy case, the thread has already been here, so we just return its thread-local data.

In the case where a new thread has called into the library, we need to create its thread-local data. If we have fewer threads than the limit, this proceeds quickly: we create the data, store it in the map, and return it (`createThreadLocalData()` could be replaced with a `new`, but I tend to like factory methods in code like this).

The sad case is where the table is already at its maximum size when a new thread enters. Because we have no way to know when a thread is done, I chose to simply leave the dead threads in the table until we need space -- just like the JVM and memory management. If we need space, we execute `doCleanup()` to purge the dead threads (garbage). If there still isn't enough space once we've cleared dead threads, we throw (we could also implement waiting, but that would increase complexity and is generally a bad idea for a library).

Synchronization is important. If we have two new threads come through at the same time, we need to block one while the other tries to get added to the table. The critical section must include the *entirety* of checking, optionally cleaning up, and adding the new item. If you don't make that *entire* operation atomic, you risk exceeding your limit. Note, however, that the initial `get()` does *not* need to be in the atomic section, so we don't need to synchronize the entire method.

OK, on to `doCleanup()`: this simply iterates the map and looks for threads that are no longer alive. If it finds one, it calls the destructor ("anti-factory") for its thread-local data:

```
private void doCleanup() {
    for (Thread thread : threadTable.keySet()) {
        if (! thread.isAlive()) {
            MyThreadLocalData data = threadTable.remove(thread);
            if (data != null) {
                destroyThreadLocalData(data);
            }
        }
    }
```

}

Even though this function is called from within a synchronized block, it's written as if it could be called concurrently. One of the nice features of `ConcurrentHashMap` is that any iterators it produces can be used concurrently, *and give a view of the map at the time of call*. However, that means that two threads might check the same map entry, and we don't want to call the destructor twice. So we use `remove()` to get the entry, and if it's null we know that it's already been (/being) cleaned up by another thread.

As it turns out, you might want to call the method concurrently. Personally, I think the "clean up when necessary" approach is simplest, but your thread-local data might be expensive to hold if it's not going to be used. If that's the case, create a [Timer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html) that will repeatedly call `doCleanup()`:

```
public Timer scheduleCleanup(long interval) {
    TimerTask task = new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            doCleanup();
        }
    };
    Timer timer = new Timer(getClass().getName(), true);
    timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(task, 0L, interval);
    return timer;
}
```

Comment: Wow! Thanks for the great description and code. Your suggestion is what I was afraid I'd have to do but I'm glad to know that there wasn't some easier/more obvious solution out there. I like the idea about leaving dead threads in there until we need the space.  Sorry I can't vote up your answer b/c I don't have enough reputation. :-(

Answer (score 2):

Normally you would let the GC clean up resources.  You can add a component to the thread which will be cleaned up when it is not longer accessible.

If you use a custom ThreadGroup, it will me notified when a thread is removed from the group. If you start the JAR using a thread in the group, it will also be part of the group.  You can also change a threads group so it will be notifed via reflection.

However, polling the threads every few second is likely to be simpler.

Comment: *so I have no control over when or how many threads come through.* - I don't think the OP is using a custom ThreadGroup. So, maybe polling is the only solution. :P

Comment: @TheLostMind I assumed OP was a developer and can add a custom class.

Comment: ya.. If he can add a custom class, then its fine .

Comment: How will a custom `ThreadGroup` be notified when a thread is removed?

Comment: @Holger The last time I did this I modified the ThreadGroup and unfortunately that still seems to eb the only option.  Perhaps that is not a good idea however `threadTerminated(Thread)` will be called.

Comment: Oh, now I see, my question arose because I happened to look at a JRE which didn’t have such method. Oracle’s JRE 7+ has it. I suggest that explains perfectly why overriding an implementation specific package-private method is not a good idea… Btw., executing code within a thread that is claimed to be terminated… doesn’t feel right…

Comment: @Holger This is what the uncaught exception handler does. I would have thought changing a java.lang Class is worse. ;)

Answer (score 2):

You can use a combination of ThreadLocal and WeakReference.  Create some sort of "ticket" object and when a thread enters the library, create a new ticket and put it in the ThreadLocal.  Also, create a WeakReference (with a ReferenceQueue) to the ticket instance and put it in a list inside your library.  When the thread exits, the ticket will be garbage collected and your WeakReference will be queued.  by polling the ReferenceQueue, you can essentially get "events" indicating when a thread exits.

Comment: Thanks but I need this list to be accurate in real-time. I cannot wait for the GC to clear out these "tickets" at some later time.

Comment: well, if you are planning no polling the currently running threads, then you aren't getting "real time" anyway.  this method should be a lot less resource intensive.

Comment: Any reason you need the "ticket" rather than simply using a `WeakReference` that points at the thread itself?

Comment: Although I'd probably think of using phantom references in this case.

Comment: @kdgregory - no reason for the ticket other than that i didn't think of using the Thread itself (although that could be potentially referenced elsewhere even after the thread has finished running).

Comment: @kdgregory - using a PhantomReference would delay the feedback loop (since WeakReferences have to be cleared before PhantomReferences).