# How to send a notification to the thread based on its name or id? Is it possible?

Tags: java, multithreading

Context: java inter-thread communication

How to send a notification to the thread based on its name or id?
Is it possible?

We can not communicate a particular thread in Java, 
We do not know when scheduler going assign the CPU to the thread.
Then what is the purpose of methods `public void setName(String name)`, `public String getName()` and `public int getId()` methods of `Thread` class.

These methods helps for only developers to identify the thread or we can use it for inter-thread communication?

Comment: *"We can not communicate a particular thread, Is this correct?"*  I don't understand what you are asking here.

Comment: @Stephen Can I communicate a specific thread in java?

Comment: Still doesn't make sense.  Java doesn't "communicate" threads, and it is not meaningful in a non-technical sense either.

Comment: Assume: 10 threads are at runnable state I want to notify "MyThread". Can I do it?

Comment: Ah!  So you are >>actually<< asking if you can send a notification to a thread based on its name or thread id.  Correct?

Comment: The problem is that in Java you send notifications to threads waiting on objects.  It requires cooperation between the thread that is doing the notifying and the one that is being notified ... and it is hard to see how doing that with thread names / ids is going to work.  In short, your requirement is too vague.

Comment: How to sending a notification to a thread based on its name or thread id? is my qustion

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84436/discussion-between-scarlett-rose-and-stephen-c).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is the above code is valid?

No it isn't.  `Thread` is a classname, but `Thread.getName()` is an instance method.  Therefore, that code will give you a compilation error.

However, this would be valid:

```
if (Thread.currentThread().getName().equals("MyThread1")){
     //MyThread1 specific code here
}
```

Now it is unclear whether this does what you expect.  It certainly doesn't communicate with a thread in any sense.  It simply says, "if I am running on a thread whose name is `"MyThread1"` then do certain things".

---

Now that finally we have a clear statement of your question ....

> How to sending a notification to a thread based on its name or thread id?

Assuming that you mean a wait/notify style notification, then in general, you can't.

A notify is sent by making an `Object.notify()` call on some object, and is received by another thread that is currently blocked in an `Object.wait()` call on the same object.

- If the notify call is made when no thread waiting, then it is lost.
- If the notify call is made on the wrong object, then it is lost.

In general an arbitrary thread won't be notifiable this way.  It will be doing something else. The fact that it is possible to identify an thread based on its name or id is actually beside the point.

What you should really be doing here is:

1. Identify the style of notification you require.  Synchronous vs asynchronous?  Guaranteed delivery or not?  1-to-1 or 1-to-many?  Is other information passed?
2. Choose the most appropriative primitive for "notifying".  For example:

   - wait/notify
   - Semaphores
   - barriers / latches
   - queues / dequeues
   - locks
   - interupts
   - etcetera
3. Design your application so that there is a Map or something that will map from a thread's name to the appropriate "notification channel" object for notifying it.  Or better still, don't.

Comment: "MyThread1" is sample thread name, which is in runnable state thread pool

Answer (score 3):

Well, you can programmatically [find a thread by its name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15370120/get-thread-by-name). With the [Thread object](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html) in hand, you can `start()` it, `run()` it, get its state, its stack trace, `join()` it, `interrupt()` [and much more](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html). This is clearly inter-thread communication. So yes, you can communicate with a given thread if you know its name.

However I don't think that finding a thread by its name makes a lot of sense in typical situations.

Comment: Agreed, I only use thread names for debugging and checking logs.

Comment: Agree with Timo: I use thread name in logs, in order to check whether it was a scheduler where exceptions occur, or a HTTP Request.