# Get access to existing thread

Tags: java, android, multithreading, bluetooth

In my program I have a `BroadcastReceiver`, where I'm creating a new Bluetooth ConnectedThread.

```
ConnectedThread thread = new ConnectedThread(btSocket);
thread.start();
```

But I need to get access this thread in different scope (method outside from receiver). `thread.write(bytesWrite);`  I don't want to create another thread, I need to get access to existing one. Moreover, I can't declare thread outside from receiver, because I can't put the unknown parameter (btSocket).

How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is by keeping a `static` reference to the thread you just created. In your received, do:

```
public YourReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
  @Nullable public static ConnectedThread thread;

  public void onReceive(...) {
    thread = new ConnectedThread(btSocket);
    thread.start();
  } 
}
```

Then from whatever class you're in, you can reference the thread via `YourReceiver.thread`.

The main disadvantage of this approach is that keeping a static reference to the `ConnectionThread` is wasteful (the `ConnectionThread` won't be GC'd until you release that reference) so make sure that you nullify it whenever you're done.
Another problem that you might run into is that you make sure to check the internal state of the thread before using it, namely whether it's still running or has already finished executing.

Answer (score 0):

You have at least 3 threads :

1. the ConnectThread
2. the one that creates the ConnectThread
3. the thread in a different scope

To get a reference of the ConnectThread, you need something that is available in thread 2 (the one that creates the ConnectThread) and thread 3 (the thread in a different scope).

A simple approach could be, to have a class ThreadHolder with a static variable that holds a reference of the thread :

```
public class ThreadHolder{
  public static ConnectedThread connectedThread
}
```

In thread 2 you set the reference :

```
ConnectedThread thread = new ConnectedThread(btSocket);
ThreadHolder.connectedThread=thread;
thread.start();
```

In thread 3 you find it :

```
ConnectedThread thread = ThreadHolder.connectedThread=thread;
//now do what you need with the thread
```

Alternatively you can give ConnectedThread a name in thread 2 :

thread.setName("connectedThread")

And find it in htread 3 using this method :

```
public Thread getThreadByName(String threadName) {
   for (Thread t : Thread.getAllStackTraces().keySet()) {
    if (t.getName().equals(threadName)) return t;
   }
  return null;
}
```

see also [find thread by name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15370120/get-thread-by-name)