# Is there a way to check to see if a timer is running with the Timer Java class?

Tags: android, kotlin, timer

I want to check and see if my Timer is still running after my Android app crashes or closes. If it is not running I would like to create a new timer. I set a name for the timer so is there a function to get the Timer by name?

In the `onCreate()` function of the MainActivity I would check to see if the timer is running and if not, I would just call the function to create a new one.

```
private fun createTimer(){
        Timer("SayHello",false).schedule(startTime.time){
          Log.d(TAG, "hello")
        }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> is there a function to get the Timer by name

No. They aren't stored anywhere to get them *from*, unless you do that yourself. Ok, technically you could [find the thread by name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15370120/get-thread-by-name) because each `Timer` creates a thread, but you couldn't get back the timer object from it.

But if "Android app crashes or closes", any timers it created certainly aren't running.